# Use mapply function instead of apply function in shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to generate the same result I am getting, but instead of using the `apply` function I would like to use the `mapply` function in `data_subset`.

This question is very similar to this one: [Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599800/error-in-usemethodselect-no-applicable-method-for-select-applied-to-an-o)

So instead of using em `data_subset`:

```
All <- cbind(df2, coef = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {return_coef(data(),as.numeric(x[1]),as.Date(x[2]),x[3],var1,var2)}))
```

I'd like something like this below. It is similiar the resolved question I mentioned earlier:

```
  All<-Datas%>%
    transmute(
    Id,date2, Category,
     coef = mapply(return_coef, list(cur_data()), as.numeric(Id),as.Date(date2), Category, var1 , var2))
```

From the figures below you can see that I'm getting different results. However, I believe that the values ​​would have to be the same.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)


df1 <- structure(
  list(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    date1 = c("2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06"),
    date2 = c("2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-09","2022-01-10"),
    Week = c("Sunday","Monday","Sunday","Monday"),
    Category = c("EFG", "ABC","EFG","ABC"),
    DR1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
    DRM0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM02 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM04 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


return_coef <- function(df1, idd,dmda, CategoryChosse, var1, var2) {
  
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DRM"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x,Id, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median),.groups = 'drop')
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DRM\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(Id:Category, DRM0_DRM0_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DRM")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DRM", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,20)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DRM"), sum),.groups = 'drop') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DRM(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c(var1,var2)
  datas$days <- datas[[as.name(var1)]]
  datas$numbers <- datas[[as.name(var2)]]
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((ymd(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  mod <- lm(numbers ~ I(days^2), datas)
  coef<-coef(mod)[1]
  val<-as.numeric(coef(mod)[1])
  
  
  return(val)
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("PAGE1",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                               ))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data<-reactive(df1)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "",
                   min = min(data()$date1),
                   max   = max(data()$date2),
                   format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
    
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    var1 = "Days"
    var2 = "Numbers"
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    df1<-subset(data(), as.Date(date2) %in% days)
    Datas <- subset(df1, date2 >= date1)
    df2 <- Datas %>% select(Id,date2,Category)
    All <- cbind(df2, coef = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {return_coef(data(),as.numeric(x[1]),as.Date(x[2]),x[3],var1,var2)}))
    
   })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    
    data_subset()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It really is best (and courteous) to reduce questions to the minimum required For example, *we don't need fancy themes*, unless it is a clear component of the question (it is not). Further, your `df1` has no dates, so the daterange input is messed up, I expect it should be a `Date`-class. I would have assumed that given where this code suggests you are in R programming, you should be able to give class-correct data and not require us to wade through fixing minutiae like that.

Comment: Even correcting for that (`df1[2:3] <- lapply(df1[2:3], as.POSIXct, tz="UTC")`), using this data, I can only run a query that ranges from 1-12 to 1-12, I'm not sure what is expected given such a limited range.

Comment: Lastly, on the theme of giving a minimum question, please realize that not everybody chooses to load the entire `tidyverse` for questions. I do not. I don't have the tidyverse meta-package installed. So I then go through the iterative process of finding out what is really needed. In this case, I removed `shinythemes` (and the `theme=`) and `tidyverse` with no adverse effects. [Mcve], please, it really can make a difference. This is too much code to quickly play with, and the little things have added up.

Comment: might I suggest that you act quickly? You have 2 out of 3 close votes atm. If you are going to make changes to your question (as advised), then I suggest you delete the question right now, then when you have time come back and [edit] then undelete the question. Temporary deletion prevents down-votes and close-votes while deleted. (Or you can wait, it may be closed without action, or somebody may see something I have not.) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @r2evans, I tweaked the question to try to make it more understandable, please let me know, if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your original `apply` code, you're using `data()`, which is the shiny-reactive *full* dataset; but in your attempt with `mapply`, you're using `cur_data()`, which is dplyr-speak for (in this case) `Datas`, a *subset* of the whole dataset.

If you replace your previous assignment

```r
    All <- cbind(df2, coef = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {
      return_coef(data(), as.numeric(x[1]), as.Date(x[2]), x[3], var1, var2)
    }))
```

with

```r
    All <- Datas %>%
      transmute(
        Id, date2, Category,
        coef = mapply(return_coef, list(data()), Id, as.Date(date2), Category, var1, var2)
      )
    All
#   Id      date2 Category      coef
# 3  1 2022-01-09      EFG -32.14286
# 4  1 2022-01-10      ABC  50.00000
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted. One question: is it possible to compare calculation time using `apply` and `mapply` functions? If yes, which function can I use? Thank you again!

Comment: You can use `bench::mark` or `microbenchmark`, both are fairly good at that. Beyond benchmarking, though, I'm always wary of using `apply(df, 1, ...)` (rowwise) with whole frames, as it converts it to a `matrix` first (which can be okay class-wise but still has some concerns). Even if `apply` is as fast as `mapply`, I'd be concerned about other things happening under the hood, preferring the class-preserving `mapply` any day.

Comment: Got it, so @r2evans, I'll check out some of those options you commented on, thanks for that. In this example you saw, it goes super fast to generate `coef`, but I have a much larger database, the `coef` values are generated, but it takes too long, and it is exactly the same as the code in the question above. What would you do in this case?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? You are doing a LOT of work in `return_coef`, and I wonder how much of it is actually required (or perhaps done inefficiently). The `profvis` package can be helpful for this, and while it can take some deep concentration to figure out what it's telling you, the bottom line is that the profiling is best done with real-size data (not what we have here in this question). (I'm not in a position to review code to that degree atm.)

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for helping me with this question and for the subsequent answers.