# Error: Problem with `mutate()` column in R

Tags: r

This question is very similar to this one [Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599800/error-in-usemethodselect-no-applicable-method-for-select-applied-to-an-o), what is different is a few things in the `return_coef` function and it's also that I'm filtering the function by `Id`, `date` and `Category`, and in the answered question, it was just by `date` and `Category`.

You will see below that I can generate the coefficients for each **Id/date/Category**, but when I ask to do it for everyone at once, I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `coef`.
i `coef = mapply(...)`.
x negative length vectors are not allowed
```

**Executable code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    date1 = c("2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06"),
    date2 = c("2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-09","2022-01-10"),
    Week = c("Sunday","Monday","Sunday","Monday"),
    Category = c("EFG", "ABC","EFG","ABC"),
    DR1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200),
    DRM01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM02 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM04 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM05 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

return_coef <- function (df1, idd, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  selection = startsWith(names(df1), "DRM0")
  
  df1[selection][is.na(df1[selection])] = 0
  
  data1<-subset(df1,df1$date2<df1$date1)
  
  dt1 <- as.data.table(data1)
  
  cols <- grep("^DRM0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)
  
  med <- 
    dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
    ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Id, Category, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DRM0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(Id:Category, DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col())%>%
    data.frame()

  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(Id==idd, date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DRM0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DRM0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    dplyr::filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DRM0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DRM0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("var1","var2")
  datas$days <- datas[[as.name("var1")]]
  datas$numbers <- datas[[as.name("var2")]]
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DR1"), mean), .groups = 'drop')
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    val<-as.numeric(m)
  }
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(numbers ~ b1*days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    val<-as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  }
  
  
  return(val)
  
}
```

---

Find the `coef` one by one **(It works)**:

```
return_coef(df1,"1","2022-01-09","EFG")
[1] 200
return_coef(df1,"1","2022-01-10","ABC")
[1] 250
```

---

Find all `coef` at once **(Does not work)**

```
subset_df1 <- subset(df1, date2 > date1)

All<-subset_df1%>%
  transmute(
    Id,date2,Category,
    coef = mapply(return_coef, list(cur_data()), Id, as.Date(date2), Category))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `coef`.
i `coef = mapply(...)`.
x negative length vectors are not allowed
```

---

```
dput(head(df1))
structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1), date1 = structure(c(1641427200, 
1641427200, 1641427200, 1641427200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), date2 = structure(c(1641081600, 1641168000, 1641686400, 
1641772800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Week = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Monday"), Category = c("EFG", 
    "ABC", "EFG", "ABC"), DR1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200), DRM01 = c(300, 
    300, 300, 300), DRM02 = c(300, 300, 300, 300), DRM03 = c(300, 
    300, 300, 300), DRM04 = c(300, 300, 300, 300), DRM05 = c(300, 
    250, 350, 350)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function seems to be use `df1` as the full data

```
library(dplyr)
subset_df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(coef = return_coef(df1, Id, date2, Category)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 12
     Id date1      date2      Week   Category   DR1 DRM01 DRM02 DRM03 DRM04 DRM05   coef
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2022-01-06 2022-01-09 Sunday EFG        200   300   300   300   300   350   200
2     1 2022-01-06 2022-01-10 Monday ABC        200   300   300   300   300   350   250
```

#### Update

In the new dataset, the columns 'date1', 'date2' are POSIXct, convert to `Date` class and it should work

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(c(date1, date2), as.Date))
subset_df2 <- subset(df2, date2 > date1)
subset_df2 %>%
    rowwise %>%
   mutate(coef = return_coef(df2, Id, date2, Category)) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 2 × 12
     Id date1      date2      Week   Category   DR1 DRM01 DRM02 DRM03 DRM04 DRM05  coef
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2022-01-06 2022-01-09 Sunday EFG        200   300   300   300   300   350   200
2     1 2022-01-06 2022-01-10 Monday ABC        200   300   300   300   300   350   250
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
subset_df1  %>% 
 transmute(Id, date2, Category, 
  coeff = pmap_dbl(across(c(Id, date2, Category)),
    ~ return_coef(df1, ..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

-output

```
   Id      date2 Category coeff
3  1 2022-01-09      EFG   200
4  1 2022-01-10      ABC   250
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, just one question: Do you know if using `pmap_dbl` is faster than using `mapply` to generate the `coefs`?

Comment: @Antonio It may not be, but with `pmap`, you can have some type checks with `_dbl`

Comment: Hi akrun, I have a question. I'm managing to generate these `coef` values ​​as you did above. However, I'm having problems when `df1` is an excel. I have a database similar to the one in the question, but in excel. So I did it like this: `df1<-read_excel('C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/test.xlsx')`. I can generate the coefficients if it's one by one, but if I do them all at once, it gives the same error. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: @Antonio can you show the `dput(head(df1))`

Comment: Yes, I inserted it in the question, because I couldn't enter everything as an answer.

Comment: @Antonio isn't this related to the date element i.e .`return_coef(df1,"1","2022-01-02","EFG")` returns error

Comment: @Antonio the reason is that your date columns are POSIXct, instead of `Date` class and thus it affected.  Please check the update

Comment: @Antonio it is just when you read with `read_excel`, it automatically checks the column type and assign the type unless you specify the type