# Generate coefficient values for all dates/categories

Tags: r

I made two codes with the same functionality, which is to generate the coefficient values for all date/category of my dataset `df1`. The first code works, however, the second one doesn't. I would like to solve this problem of the second code. For this second code I did according to the resolution of this question: [Inserting new data into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347416/inserting-new-data-into-a-table), which is very similar.

**First code**

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-29","2021-06-29","2021-07-06","2021-07-06","2021-07-06"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC","DDE"),
       Week= c("Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,0,2,2),
       DR01 = c(4,1,0,3,2), DR02= c(4,2,0,2,4),DR03= c(9,5,0,7,1),
       DR04 = c(5,4,0,2,1),DR05 = c(5,4,0,4,1),
       DR06 = c(2,4,0,2,4),DR07 = c(2,5,3,4,5),
       DR08 = c(3,4,5,4,4),DR09 = c(2,3,7,4,5),DR10 = c(2,3,9,4,5),DR13 = c(2,3,10,4,5)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

return_coef <- function(dmda, CategoryChosse) {

  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])-2):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
    m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
   m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
   if (nrow(datas)<=2){
   as.numeric(m)
   }
  
  else{
  mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
        }
}

cbind(df1 %>% select(date2, Category), coef = mapply(return_coef, df1$date2, df1$Category))
       date2 Category       coef
1 2021-06-29      FDE  5.3478916
2 2021-06-29      ABC  1.3694779
3 2021-07-06      FDE -0.7451236
4 2021-07-06      ABC -0.5182055
5 2021-07-06      DDE  2.0000000
```

**Second code**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-29","2021-06-29","2021-07-06","2021-07-06","2021-07-06"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC","DDE"),
       Week= c("Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,0,2,2),
       DR01 = c(4,1,0,3,2), DR02= c(4,2,0,2,4),DR03= c(9,5,0,7,1),
       DR04 = c(5,4,0,2,1),DR05 = c(5,4,0,4,1),
       DR06 = c(2,4,0,2,4),DR07 = c(2,5,3,4,5),
       DR08 = c(3,4,5,4,4),DR09 = c(2,3,7,4,5),DR10 = c(2,3,9,4,5),DR13 = c(2,3,10,4,5)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

dates <- subset(df1, date2 > date1, select = date2)$date2

  map_dfr(dates, ~ {
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])-2):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    as.numeric(m)
  }
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  }
  
  tibble(dates = .x, coef = coef(model)[2])
  
}) %>%
  mutate(dates = format(ymd(dates), "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: I posted the solution. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code, it is using `mapply` from `base R` which can take multiple input arguments, where as `map` can only take a single argument i.e. it is more like `lapply` from `base R`.  If we want to have two arguments, use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1_sub <- subset(df1, date2 > date1)
dates <- df1_sub$date2
categ <- df1_sub$Category
 map2_dfr(dates, categ, ~ {
  dmda <- .x
  CategoryChosse <- .y
  x<-df1 %>% 
    select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median), .groups = 'drop')
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum), .groups = "drop") %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])-2):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean), .groups = "drop")
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    as.numeric(m)
  }
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  }
  
  tibble(dates = .x, coef = coef(mod)[2]) %>% 
      mutate(Category = .y)
  
}) %>%
  mutate(dates = format(ymd(dates), "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  dates        coef Category
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
1 29/06/2021  5.35  FDE     
2 29/06/2021  1.37  ABC     
3 06/07/2021 -0.745 FDE     
4 06/07/2021 -0.518 ABC     
5 06/07/2021  2.00  DDE
```

Comment: Akrun, perfect!  Can you insert the Category column in the output also like the other resolution?

Comment: @JVieira updated with Category column

Comment: Thanks again akrun! =)